# What are "groups" and why there are used for? -- THREE.js

Tags: three.js

I was gonna write a HELP in gitub however it says "plaese use StackOverflow". So i am writing it here

I am trying to write a new .js file for Three.js. In [BoxBufferGeometry.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/geometries/BoxBufferGeometry.js#L193), it looks like, it's adding 1 group for every 6 indices. For a box there are 6 groups. For CylinderGeometry there are 3 groups. 2 for top and bottom disks and 1 for cylinder.

So in short, can you explain how and why they are used for? Thanks for answer.

Comment: This is a confusing variable name. Lowercase group in buffergeometry is not the uppercase Group.js class. To explain, a square side is made of two triangles, e.g. two faces. A face needs 3 indices to refer to three vertexes. 4 vertexes are shared. 6 face indices create a single square plane. These indices groups are simply an array, used for assigning a material index in the parent bufferGeometry class so you can do things like assign a texture per side. The uppercase Group.js class is a special class the renderer accepts, but does not itself hold any geometry.

Comment: @Radio Thanks for pointing out. Now i realize, they are different. I made an edit.

Comment: I hope I also explained well enough why groups exist in the primitive geometry types. Those groups literally just allowing multi-material support for texturing specific sides.